# How to call my ajax function/fetch with a btn

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, api

Im learning how to use API's with ajax in jquery.

I fetched "bored api" in my html page, and I want to update it or run the function again, by pressing a button and without refreshing the page.

I know I would write the function name in my onclick method, but I can't see where the function name should be placed or is.

```
<p id="activity"></p>

                  <script>
                    $(function () {
                      $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: "https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity",
                        success: function (data) {
                          console.log("Success", data) 
                          document.getElementById("activity").textContent = data.activity;
                        }
                      })
                    })          
              </script>
              </form>

            <button onclick="()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: If you're struggling to understand [Function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions), I would suggest re-visiting the fundamentals of JavaScript before continuing any further with more complex tasks (such as AJAX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on this example from W3 Schools:
[Example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick_copy)

It should look something like this:

```
<p id="activity"></p>

              <script>
                function doApiRequest() {
                  $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: "https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity",
                    success: function (data) {
                      console.log("Success", data) 
                      document.getElementById("activity").textContent = data.activity;
                    }
                  });
                }          
          </script>
          </form>

        <button onclick="doApiRequest()">Click me</button>
```

You do not need to encapsulate the method inside jquery. and this way, we give it a name, that we can call.

Comment: Do not confuse the W3C (a standards organisation) with W3Schools (a low-quality, advertising-riddled, commercial site)

Comment: it provides a reasonable example for the asked question, though.